# Postman preview 'Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found'

Tags: c#, postman, http-status-code-404, .net-framework-version

I have a MVC .NetFramework project and I am trying to test a web api using postman.
My controller has the following content:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using static ServerSide.Controllers.RegisterController;

namespace ServerSide.Controllers
{
    public class RegisterController : ApiController
    {
        
        public class Data
        {
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
            public string repeatPass { get; set; }
        }

        [HttpPost]     
        public IHttpActionResult Posthdf([FromBody] string data)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
                return BadRequest("Date invalide");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("***************************************EmailRegister " + data + "***************************************");
            return Ok("lalala");
        }
    }
}
```

My WebApiConfig.cs is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ServerSide.App_Start
{
    public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

What I get in postman when I press the Send button:
[image]

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What if you try using a URL of `/api/Register/Posthdf`?

Comment: @DavidG
Using `http://localhost:54111/api/Register/Posthdf` as URL, I get the same error. Showld I add something else in Global.asax.cs file in order to be able to access the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your API doesn't know the route '/api/Register'. You can set that by assigning a route to the controller.

```
[Route("Register")]        
public class RegisterController : ApiController
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but if I put `[Route("Register")] `, I still get the error. My guess is that the type of project or something inside it doesn't allow me to access the controller.

Comment: The [Route("api/Register/Posthdf")] must be above the method called Posthdf

Comment: @Little_Dev, I put the line code as you suggested, but with no success. I get the same error. Showld I add something else in Global.asax.cs file in order to be able to access the controller?